# What would cause PayPal's AdaptivePayments API to return a " internal server error. please check the server logs for details"?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on integrating PayPal's AdaptivePayment API but everytime I make a call I am getting the error "Internal server error. Please check the server logs for details" returned from the CURL call. I believe I have all the required headers. Has anyone else had this issue? My code is below:

```
            $appID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
            $username = "***********";
            $password = "***********";
            $signature = "**********";

            $endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/";

            $headers = array(
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $username,
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ". $password,
                "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ". $signature,
                "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
                "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
                "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ". $appID
            );

            $packet = array(
                "actionType" => "PAY",
                "currencyCode" => "USD",
                "cancelUrl" => "cancel.html",
                "returnUrl" => "success.html",
                "receiverList" => array(
                    "receiver" => array(
                        array(
                            "amount" => "1.00",
                            "email" => "example@gmail.com",
                            "primary" => true
                        ),
                        array(
                            "amount" => "0.50",
                            "email" => "example2@gmail.com",
                            "primary" => false
                        )
                    )
                ),
                "requestEnvelope" => array(
                    "errorLanguage" => "en_US"
                )
            );


            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint."PAY");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

            //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($packet));

            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            if (curl_errno($ch)) 
            {
                // moving to display page to display curl errors
                echo curl_errno($ch);
                echo curl_error($ch);

                  //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "RESPONSE";
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo $response;
                curl_close($ch);
            }
```

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. Have you checked the logs as instructed?

Comment: How can you check PayPal's logs?

Comment: It's not PayPal's logs.  It's your log.  As mentioned in your original post, you'll need to create logs for cURL that you can check to see if there any errors there.  Also check general PHP error logs, and provide sample of the API request you're sending if none of that leads you anywhere.

Comment: No the error is meaningless, what you see in your own log is the error response from PayPal telling you to check the logs.  It's basically a bug in PayPal, they should return 400 Bad Request if you send wrong/missing parameters. Instead in many cases you get 500 Internal Server Error, indicating an unhandled exception on PayPal's side.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint URL is wrong, it should be:

```
$endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";
```